# Do I need to enable LDAP authentication for my Cache instance ot use LDAP auntentication in a single CPS application?

Tags: intersystems-iris

Currently, I am working on a CSP application that is supposed to generate reports. Users will have varying access to said reports. To achieve that, I plan to use LDAP (because it's used in other systems where those users already exist). Documentation does not provide enough information, so I'd like a clarification:
Do I need to enable LDAP authentication for the whole Cache instance to use LDAP authentication in a single CSP application in that instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. First configure LDAP authentication for the whole Caché (or InterSystems IRIS) instance then enable LDAP authentication for the particular web application.

Quoting [docs](https://docs.intersystems.com/iris20201/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCAS_LDAP#GCAS_ldap_overview) steps are following:

- Enable LDAP and related features for the instance.
- Create an LDAP configuration for the instance of InterSystems IRIS.
  This includes specifying the names of LDAP user properties to be used
  for setting the values of properties of InterSystems IRIS users.
- Set up a role that is required for logging into the instance.
- Enable LDAP for the instance’s relevant services and applications.
  This involves enabling LDAP for the entire instance of InterSystems
  IRIS and then enabling it for the relevant services or applications.